# How to load mysql listview data into fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

i want to load Mysql data into listview into fragment 
which contain image and text view stored previously into mysql database
this is my code but it show me error in getLayoutInflater 
how can i do this ?

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    String url = "http://giclub.esy.es/show.php";
    ListView listView;
    View myView;

    ArrayList<NewsList> Newslistitem = new ArrayList<NewsList>();

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newslayout,container,false);
        listView = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getActivity());
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("allstudents");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject respons = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String id = respons.getString("id");
                                String name = respons.getString("name");
                                String info = respons.getString("info");
                                String img = respons.getString("img");
                                Newslistitem.add(new NewsList(id,name, info, img));
                            }
                            listAllItme();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR");
            }
        }
        );
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        return myView;
    }
    public void listAllItme() {
        listAdpter lA = new listAdpter(Newslistitem);
        listView.setAdapter(lA);
    }

   /* public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(),NewsFragment.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }*/
    class listAdpter extends BaseAdapter {
        ArrayList<NewsList> listA = new ArrayList<NewsList>();

        public listAdpter(ArrayList<NewsList> listA) {
            this.listA = listA;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listA.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return listA.get(position).id;
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.news_itm, null);
            //TextView id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_id);
            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textaddress);
            TextView info = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_info);
            ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.newspic);
            // id.setText(listA.get(position).id);
            name.setText(listA.get(position).name);
            info.setText(listA.get(position).info);
            Picasso.with(NewsFragment.this.getActivity()).load("http://giclub.esy.es/image/" + listA.get(position).img).into(img);
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

NewsList.java

```
public class NewsList {
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String info;
    public String img;

    public NewsList(String id ,String name, String info, String img) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.info = info;
        this.img = img;
    }
}
```

news_itm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/newspic"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="اقرأ المزيد"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:id="@+id/text_info"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="35dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/textaddress"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all i will recommend to split the code between the ui and the data access, then load the data in a different threat and not in the ui thread

try loading the screen first with a dummy data to check that the layout and the screen works properly then connect it to the "DAL" with your saved data

Comment: i'm beginner and this code works for activity not fragment that's all the issue i want list view in fragment

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listfragments

Comment: thx for that but it's easy to made listview fulled of  offline array data ,,, i want to load this data from mysql database

Answer (score 0):

Your are inflating the newslayout While Your layout is `**news_itm.xml**`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
 myView inflater.inflate(R.layout.**newslayout**,container,false);
```